# handling x86-64 microarchitecture levels in Debian package names

Tags: debian, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-architecture, debian-packaging

I'm planning to build different versions of intense numerical program for x86-64 architectures.  Conveniently, in 2020, 4 levels of x86-64 microarchitecture were defined that can be passed to the compiler via the "-march" flag.
Thus, for GCC 11 (and similarly for Clang 12), I should be able to use AVX, AVX2, and LZCNT instructions by specifying

```
gcc -march=x86-64-v3
```

and expand that to AVX512 by

```
gcc -march=x86-64-v4
```

If I create a Debian package out of this, it might be called

```
mynumerics_22.04_amd64.deb
```

However, there are really two versions.  Running the `x86-64-v4` version on a `x86-64-v3` machine results in SIGILL (illegal instruction). Some suggested this to me:

```
mynumerics_22.04_amd64-x3.deb
mynumerics_22.04_amd64-x4.deb
```

Where x3 stands for x86-64-v3, x4 for x86-64-v4.
But I think this violates Debian 'arch' specifier rules.
Adding it to the version part of the package name results in:

```
mynumerics_22.04-x3_amd64.deb
mynumerics_22.04-x4_amd64.deb
```

But this can be interpreted by the package manager as x4 being a later version.
I am thinking about suffixing the name. Thus:

```
mynumerics-x3_22.04_amd64.deb
mynumerics-x4_22.04_amd64.deb
```

A similar microarchitecture issue might happen in the ARM aarch64 world. From my reading, ARMv8-A supports "Advanced SIMD (Neon)"; ARMv8.2-A supports "Scalable Vector Extension (SVE)".  This might yield,

```
mynumerics-a8_22.04_arm64.deb
mynumerics-a82_22.04_arm64.deb
```

Is there a better way to handle microarchitecture level differences?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it not an option to include both implementations and select between them at runtime (e.g. because of size concerns)?

Comment: @MonatheMonad For a small number of affected functions, that might be doable. For a library of 100-200 numerical functions, this gets out of hand. In effect, the source code would need to be duplicated (#included ??) for each variant architecture. For GCC, the way to do this is something like:
int core2_func (void) __ attribute __ (( __ target __ ("arch=core2")));
int sse3_func (void) __ attribute __ ((__ target __ ("sse3")));